# How stop SCons build if any SConscript is missing?

Tags: python, scons

SCons is continues to build even if some SConscript files are missing during build time. For example, I've source structure like this:

```
├── a
│   └── test1.c
├── b
│   ├── SConscript
│   └── test2.c
└── SConstruct
```

In SConstruct I'm calling two SConscript files  where one of the SConscript is missing.

```
SConscript('a/SConscript')

SConscript('b/SConscript')
```

I got a warning message when run "scons" command.

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: Ignoring missing SConscript 'a/SConscript'
File "/home/srbd/workspace/programming/scons_demo/SConstruct", line 1, in <module>
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
gcc -o b/test2.o -c b/test2.c
gcc -o b/test2 b/test2.o
scons: done building targets.
```

But it's showing overall scons build has successfully completed.

In my real system, I've lot's source folders/files where some of SConscript may not exist when building. It's difficult get notice those missing files only by warning message when overall build is showing success.

I've searched among scons parameters but found no useful parameter.

Is there anyway I can stop build if one of the SConscript are missing and show build as failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fix for this in the development version of SCons and should be in the next release 3.0.2.

Hopefully 3.0.2 will be released before the end of the year.

Comment: can please provide me any link related with release date 3.0.2?

Comment: There is no fixed release schedule. There's a couple outstanding pull request we're trying to get in.  But hopefully before the end of the year.

Comment: No, it's not urgent now. We already make a wrapper function to handle this for now. Thanks for your reply.